# Describe the quotient ring $F[x]/(x^3-x-1)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Describe the quotient ring $F[x]/(x^3-x-1)$, where $F[x]=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. How many elements are in the ring? Is it an integral domain? a field? Which primitive roots of unity does it contain?

The quotient ring $F[x]/(x^3-x-1) \cong \{a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2: a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}, \alpha^3-\alpha-1=0 \}.$

$(i)$ I believe that $\left|\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\right|^{\deg (x^3-x-1)}=3\times 3\times 3=27$ elements in $R$.

$(ii)$ Multiplication is defined as
\begin{align*}
(a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2)(a'+b'\alpha+c'\alpha^2)&=aa'+(ab'+ba')\alpha+(ac'+bb'+ca')\alpha^2+(bc'+cb')\alpha^3+cc'\alpha^4\\
&=aa'+(ab'+ba')\alpha+(ac'+bb'+ca')\alpha^2+(bc'+cb')(\alpha+1)+cc'\alpha(\alpha+1)\\
&=aa'+cb'+bc'+(ab'+ba'+bc'+cc'+cb')\alpha+(ac'+bb'+ca'+cc')\alpha^2.
\end{align*}
By properties of addition of functions, we clearly have associativity, commutativity, and distributivity.

The ring clearly contains the additive identity 0 and the multiplicative identity 1.

For any $f=a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2\in R$, we clearly have the additive inverse of $f$ in $R$, where
$$f^{-1}=(3-a)\mod 3+\alpha(3-b)\mod 3+\alpha^2(3-c)\mod 3.$$

For any $f$, we have a multiplicative inverse of $f$ in $R$.
I confirmed this for all $27-1=26$ nonzero elements.
**I was wondering if there is a better approach to this.**

Thus, we have a field.

Since $R$ is a field, it is also an integral domain. **I found it difficult to show that the multiplication of any nonzero elements is nonzero.**

I also am not sure what it means to be a primitive root of unity in this field and would like some clarification on these points.

Comment: You just need to check that the polynomial is irreducible. Since the polynomial is degree $3$, it is either irreducible, or has a root. There are not too many roots to check. . .

Comment: So, since since the polynomial does not have any integer roots, the polynomial is irreducible. What are the primitive roots of unity?

Comment: It would make the question clearer if you told your readers that $F=\Bbb{Z}_3$ at the beginning. Otherwise the claims may not be true!

Comment: Anyway, as David Hill explained, you are expected to apply a theorem stating that if a polynomial $p(x)$ is irreducible over a field $K$, then the quotient ring $K[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is also a field. As you learned, checking for the existence of inverses is painful otherwise. You did get the number of elements correctly! For the question about primitive roots you are expected to make an observation that the multiplicative group of your field is finite. Therefore all its elements have a finite order. Therefore _____

Comment: Since all elements have finite order, all elements should be primitive roots of unity, although it may take a while to classify the orders of every element in the multiplicative group.